# philosophical modes

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand what the author means by "philosophical modes" here. Could you exemplify what it refers to?

Hutton agreed with Lewes that "feminine ability has found for itself a far more suitable sphere in novel-writing than in any other branch of literature,"37 but he attributed the predilection of women's deficiencies in intellectual training and discipline, rather than to any positive correlation between female psychology and narrative realism. For the **philosophical modes** that he valued most highly, he
thought, women substituted documentation, a copious circumstantial descriptiveness.

Link to the original text:
https://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/womens-literature-19th-century-british-women-writers

Comment: [A way or manner in which something occurs or is experienced, **expressed**, or done.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mode) Who knows what these misogynists had in their tiny pea brains.

Comment: Can you think of any examples?

Comment: I found...[Philosophy:   appearance, form, or disposition taken by a thing, or by one of its essential properties or attributes.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mode) by typing in 'philosophical mode".

Comment: Philosophical mode: a reasoned tract of writing, not those feeble-minded novels.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have an idea what it means.

Comment: @WeatherVane I expect (hope) you are putting words in the mouths of these "philosophers".

Comment: @Cascabel as any reasonable man, who knows his station in life, will unhesitatingly assert.

Comment: @WeatherVane That was amazingly equivocal.

Comment: @Cascabel I am not sure the 'mode' of that day suits me.

Comment: Ah.."as one who knows his station in life"...then perhaps you are under the thumb of this "monstrous regiment', like me. My commiserations.

Comment: @Cascabel a parody, not under orders :)